# compile with boost on ubuntu 14.04 : undefined reference to `boost::thread::get_id() const'

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu, boost

I am trying to compile a simple boost program which uses threading on ubuntu 14.04 ( using boost 1.54 ).

the output of compilation is like this:

```
09:30:25 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project sdkTest ****
make all 
Building target: sdkTest
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L"/home/khan/git/sdkLinux/libFingiSdk/Debug" -o "sdkTest"  ./src/CommunicationCoreTest.o ./src/CoreTest.o ./src/LoggerTest.o ./src/ProgramOptions.o ./src/sdkTest.o   -lfingidevicesdk -lz -lssl -lcurl -lpthread -lboost_system -lboost_regex -lboost_signals -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono -lboost_program_options -lboost_filesystem -lboost_iostreams -lboost_unit_test_framework -lpython2.7 -lboost_python
/home/khan/git/sdkLinux/libFingiSdk/Debug/libfingidevicesdk.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::get_id() const'
/home/khan/git/sdkLinux/libFingiSdk/Debug/libfingidevicesdk.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::detail::status(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/home/khan/git/sdkLinux/libFingiSdk/Debug/libfingidevicesdk.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sdkTest] Error 1

09:30:25 Build Finished (took 413ms)
```

i have install boost by using

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

and in the compilation i have added reference to libboost_thread , pthread and so on. ( infact this used to compile fine on ubuntu 12.10,boost 1.48).

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: To start with the obvious: did you include the relevant header? (boost/thread.hpp, I believe)

Comment: @Blob those are *linker* errors.

Comment: How is the libfingidevicesdk.so shared library built? Does it link boost thread?

Comment: @SamMiller bingo..that was it. it was loading the .so file from wrong location actually.thankyou very much :D

Comment: @Shrouk I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/home/khan/git/sdkLinux/libFingiSdk/Debug/libfingidevicesdk.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::get_id() const'
```

You need to link `libfingidevicesdk.so` with the boost thread library as well.